# Unable to fetch the latest state from different stores at once using Ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, redux-observable

I'm using [Ngrx](https://ngrx.io/) in my Angular application to fetch data from the store.
I created multiple stores : context, decision and status to create a functional seperation between objects.

I have a case where the UI needs to poll at the same time the latest state from 2 different stores so it can enable/disable a button.

Here is an example where the  the state of `titi` gets updated from an other component after a button gets clicked.
My problem is that with my actual code I'm not able to get the latest state for `this.titi` !
Here is my code :

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

   private titi: Titi;
   private toto: Toto;
   private unsubscribe$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

   constructor(private store: Store<State>) {}

   ngOnInit() {

      this.store.pipe(
         select(selectTiti),
         takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
      ).subscribe(state => {
         this.titi= state.titi;
      });

      this.store.pipe(
         select(selectTata),
         takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
      ).subscribe(state => {
         this.tata= state.tata;
      });

   }

   public isBtnDisabled() {
      return this.titi === 'latest value of titi' && this.tata === 'latest value of tata';
   }

   ....

   ngOnDestroy(): void {
     this.unsubscribe$.next();
     this.unsubscribe$.complete();
   }
}
```

and the UI :

```
<button [disabled] = 'isBtnDisabled()'></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a more reactive way to do it.
By using combineLatest, you'll get the latest value of each selector if the value changes into the store :

```js
isDisabled$ = combineLatest(
  this.store.select(selectTiti),
  this.store.select(selectTata)
).pipe(
  map(([titi, tata]) => // do whatever you want to check the disabled status)
);
```

You can use the async pipe into your template to subscribe so you don't have to rely to manual unsubscription into your component :

```html
<button [disabled] = 'isDisabled$ | async'></button>
```

So the final component should look like :

```js
export class MyComponent {

  public isDisabled$: Observable<boolean> = combineLatest(
  this.store.select(selectTiti),
  this.store.select(selectTata)
  ).pipe(
    map(([titi, tata]) => // do whatever you want to check the disabled status)
  );

   constructor(private store: Store<State>) {}
}
```

Comment: Actually I can't use this syntax because in my case I need to implement some buisness logic after fetching the store that I deleted for the sake of the example

Comment: you can use the `tap` operator for your business logic

Comment: I tried to use this syntax but it seems that `combineLatest()` is deprecated !
My RxJs version is `"rxjs": "^6.6.3"`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a single selector to combine these states.
https://github.com/timdeschryver/eslint-plugin-ngrx/blob/master/docs/rules/avoid-combining-selectors.md

Comment: I think that adding each time a new selector depending on the functional need will somehow overload my application :(

Comment: What's the difference between creating a selector and writing the code from your answer?  The benefit is that it's just a pure function, it's easier to test, it's memoized, easy to share, you don't need to google how to use certain RxJS operators. The selector would be 3 to 5 lines of code, your answer is 8 lines.

Answer (score -2):

Finally the solution to combine the store that I found clear and close to my implementation is :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.store.pipe(
      select(selectTiti),
      withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selectTata))),
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe(([titiState, tataState]) => {
      this.titi = titiState.titi;
      this.tata = tataState.tata;
    });
}
```

Comment: I got -2 on my answer ! can anyone who down-noted it explain me the drawback of this solution plz?